# Clear method for openpyxl

Tags: methods, openpyxl

i use excel to save data from dictionary to rebuild a dynamic created table. When putting data to table, it automatically inserts the data from dictionary to excel file. The reason is to rebuild the table when reopen the program.

The problem is that i have to clear the excel sheet, so that in case of rebuilding the dynamic table i dont se some lines from old data.

Therefor i tried some stuff to clear the sheet, but it puts only None as the result to the dictionary. That creates errors when it rebuild the table. Is there a way to inlcude such a funciton in openpyxl as it is give in vba?

workbook.worksheet.clear

Comment: Have you considered using Excel's external data source capability rather than updating the worksheets?

Comment: If all you need to do is to delete all the cells in the worksheet then I would simply delete the worksheet and recreate it.

Comment: I am sorry. But i dont like that way. Why i should delete a sheet, when i want to clear it only. On the other side its bad that by clearing content it sets None. Thats why i get problem in the traceback.  
An alternativ modul is xlwings. Can you tell me the big advantage of openpyxl ? xlwings has that function to clear content in excel sheet.